# Get-message trace output not displaying

Tags: powershell, exchange-online

When using get message trace, It doesn't display the result (just a blank space), it works for any other days I select, apart from this one - I have checked and can confirm there is only one message to display, so the count should be 1.

The image below of the output
[image]

see the code I am using below

```
$inboundMessages = Get-MessageTrace -Start $objStartDTcount1 -End $objEndDTcount1 -RecipientAddress $mailbox

# Count the number of inbound messages
$inboundMessageCount = $inboundMessages.Count

$inboundMessageCount
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

I have tried using an already working code, with a different date and the results are fine, but if I change it to the day I want that returns a blank result as well.

The day I am looking to get info from is a Sunday

Using ($inboundMessages) returns the output to show there is an email there, its just the count thats not display the number 1

update if I use, $inboundMessages | measure-object, I get (below)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed the below,

If anyone has a better/tidier solution, I would appreciate it.

Instead of using `.Count` use `| measure-object | Select-Object -expand Count`

It looks to seem that .count is not always accurate.

for example

```html
$inboundMessages = Get-MessageTrace -Start $objStartDTcount1 -End $objEndDTcount1 -RecipientAddress $mailbox

# Count the number of inbound messages
$inboundMessageCount = $inboundMessages| measure-object | Select-Object -expand Count

$inboundMessageCount
```